# Как сделать привязку к дате? unity3d

Tags: c#, unity3d, unity3d-android

Кратко опишу приложение:
У нас прописано 3 дня, на каждый день даётся свой текст, который нужно выводить.

1 день: A

2 день: B

3 день: C

Нужно, что-бы программа определяла текущую дату на Android, после чего, каждые новые сутки выдавала новый текст (новые сутки должны начинаться с 00:00).

Как это можно реализовать?

Comment: Т е не важно какой сегодня день,нужен просто глобальный таймер на 3 дня,который не будет удаляться при выходе из приложения?

Comment: Ну, по сути, да, не важно какой сегодня день. Просто этот день должен сохраняться как первый. И желательно, что-бы я смог его вывести.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В итоге, решил проблему примерно так:

Сначала создаём два DateTime:

```
System.DateTime StartTime = System.DateTime.Now; // Время на момент начала
System.DateTime CurrentTime = System.DateTime.Now; // Текущее время
```

Потом создаём метод, для сохранение времени старта:

```
void LoadStartTime()
{
    if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt("StartTimeYear") == 0)
    {
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("StartTimeYear", StartTime.Year);
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("StartTimeMonth", StartTime.Month);
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("StartTimeDay", StartTime.Day);
    }

    StartTime = new DateTime(PlayerPrefs.GetInt("StartTimeYear"), PlayerPrefs.GetInt("StartTimeMonth"), PlayerPrefs.GetInt("StartTimeDay"));
}
```

После чего помещаем его в:

```
 private void Start()
{
 // PlayerPrefs.DeleteAll(); 
    LoadStartTime();
}
```

Далее я не нашёл другого выхода как просто считать какой это день:

```
int days;

void DaysStartToCurr()
{
    if (CurrentTime > StartTime && CurrentTime < StartTime.AddDays(1)) days = 1;
    if (CurrentTime > StartTime.AddDays(1)) days = 2;
    if (CurrentTime > StartTime.AddDays(2)) days = 3;
}
```

Ну а дальше, думаю понятно что делать, просто используем "days", для определения, какой код выводить.

Answer (score 0):

Создай новый скрипт и вставь туда это

Проверь по каком поясу(вроде по Лондону) время

```
void Start () {
        Debug.Log ("Date : " +System.DateTime.UtcNow.ToString());
    }
```

добавь переменную DontDestroyOnLoad чтобы помнить день и все

Comment: Хорошо, он отображает текущее время UTC, а как сделать теперь счётчик дней?

Comment: завести переменную  для хранения даты первого входа ( https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SerializeField.html ) , не удалять при выходе из приложения,а дальше проверять текущая дата - сохраненная и получите свой день

Comment: https://tproger.ru/translations/how-to-save-and-load-your-players-progress-in-unity/ в помощь @DmitryDAN

Comment: А можно ли всё-таки как-то именно счётчик дней сделать?
То-есть, чтобы выводил: прошло N дней с такого-то момента...